# Adding 'prev' and 'next' buttons to PHP pagination. And taking out loads of numbers in the middle

Tags: php

I am dealing with a site that displays information about holidays from a MySQL database. I have successfully managed to display the information in a list format and include pagination with about 20 entries per page, but because there are quite a lot of entries, I just end up with loads of numbers at the bottom which doesn't look pretty. I was wondering if anyone knows how to include 'prev' and 'next' buttons on either side in PHP and also take some of the numbers out of the middle and replace them with '...', just like the pagination format that this site uses if you look at the bottom of the questions pages.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

//connect
mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxx') or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db('hdb') or die(mysql_error());

//pagination
$per_page = 20;

$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM `holidaytable` WHERE brandname = 'Spain'");
$count = mysql_result($pages_query, 0);
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

echo '<p>There are '.$count.' holidays<hr></p><br /><br />';

//construct query and insert values

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM holidaytable WHERE brandname = 'Spain' LIMIT $start, $per_page") or die(mysql_error());

while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   $name = $rows['name'];
   $id2 = $rows['id2'];
   $hotelname = $rows['hotelname'];
   $desc = $rows['desc'];
   $spec = $rows['spec'];
   $resort = $rows['resort'];
   $awtrack = $rows['awtrack'];
   $awthumb = $rows['awthumb'];
   $awimage = $rows['awimage'];
   $mthumb = $rows['mThumb'];
   $mlink = $rows['mlink'];
   $mimage = $rows['mimage'];
   $awcatid = $rows['awcatid'];
   $mcat = $rows['mcat'];
   $brandname = $rows['brandname'];

   echo "$id2 <br>$name <br>$hotelname <br>$desc <br><h2>$resort, $brandname</h2><br><img src='$mthumb'><br><img src='$mimage'> <br> <a href='$awtrack' target='_blank'>link</a>";
   echo "<br /><br /><hr>";
};
//pagination

if ($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages) {
for ($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++) {
    echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> </strong> ' : '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
}
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this function in one of my projects before, feel free to try this:
I am using tables but you can remove it if you want.

```
<style type="text/css">
    table,td { font-family:tahoma;}
    a.pn {padding:4px;}
</style>
<?php

 function pager($page,$rowsCount, $rowsPerPage = 10,$pageGroup = 10, $hrefPrefix='?page=')
 {
    $pageCount = ceil($rowsCount/$rowsPerPage);
    $pageIndex = $page > 1 ? $page : 1;        

    $htm = array();
    $htm[] = '<table class="pager" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">';
    $htm[] = '<tr>';
    $htm[] = '<td class="label"><label>Page ' . $pageIndex  . ' of ' . $pageCount . '</label> &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>';

    if($pageCount > 1) {            
        $offset = ($pageIndex % $pageGroup == 0) ? $pageIndex - 1 : $pageIndex;
        $startPage = (floor($offset/$pageGroup) * $pageGroup) + 1;
        $lastPage = ($startPage + $pageGroup) - 1;
        if($lastPage > $pageCount){
            $lastPage = $pageCount;
        }

        if($pageIndex > $pageGroup){
            $htm[] = '<td class="prev"><a href="'. $hrefPrefix. ($startPage-1) . '">&laquo;</a></td>';
        }

        for($i=$startPage;$i<=$lastPage; $i++) {
            if($pageIndex==$i)
                $htm[] = '<td><b>' . $i . '</b></td>';
            else
                $htm[] = '<td><a class="pn" href="' .$hrefPrefix. $i . '">' . $i . '</a></td>';
        }

        if($lastPage < $pageCount) {
            $htm[] = '<td class="next"><a href="' .$hrefPrefix. ($lastPage+1) . '">&raquo;</a></td>';
        }    
    }//pagecount>1 
    $htm[] = '</tr>';
    $htm[] = '</table>';

    echo implode("\n", $htm);
}


//sample usage:
$cp = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
$total_rows = 120;
pager($cp, $total_rows);
```

Comment: This is good! I have added it onto the end of my code replacing the old 'pagination' section at the bottom. However, there are only 7 pages of data and it still shows 12 pages at the bottom. Pages 8-12 are just blank. Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: i have tried setting 70 to total_rows and it works for me,  to effectively use the function you must at least pass the appropriate values for $page, $rowsCount and $rowsPerPage

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Zend_Paginator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.introduction.html). It implements all the things you asked for and you write much less code. You can pass it a Zend_Db instance but if you don't want to use that, you can also just pass it a PHP array, which means Zend Paginator is really a component you can use stand alone, without the need for any other Zend Framework component. A typical setup would look like this:

```
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($array);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page'));
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(8);
$paginator->setPageRange(3);
$paginator->setView($this->view);
```

And in your view:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Example</h1>
<?php if (count($this->paginator)): ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($this->paginator as $item): ?>
  <li><?php echo $item; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator,
                                    'Sliding',
                                    'my_pagination_control.phtml'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

See the [Usage chapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html) in the Zend Framework manual for an example of a pagination control `phtml` file.